# Add "active" classes to menu items using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using Grunt to build a set of static pages that operate together as a site/application. In the interest of sticking to DRY practices, I am using a package called grunt-processhtml to do "includes".

However, my "included" navigation does not have the appropriate classes to indicate the current page in the navigation. I can pull it off with JavaScript if I need to (set the active class after the menu is created, based on either a variable or the URL). However, I also stumbled across this:

[grunt-autonav](https://github.com/vmasto/grunt-autonav)

Which post-processes my assembled static files and adds the appropriate class. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to configure it for "process all of the .html files and add the appropriate classes to each of them."

My last failed attempt looks like this:

```
autonav: {
  options: {
    parent: '.nav'
  },
  dev: {
    src: '<%= dirs.purgatory %>/html/**/*.html',
    dest: '<%= dirs.dev %>'
  }
}
```

However, the plugin doesn't seem to want to use this kind of input for the source:

> Warning: Unable to read
>   "purgatory/html/download.html,purgatory/html/upload.html" file (error
>   code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

It sees my two HTML files but doesn't know how to take it from there. I can't tell if I have a configuration error or if the plugin just doesn't work this way. The sample given in their documentation seems to require specifying every single page that needs its nav customized. But it might be a reading comprehension issue.

Does anybody know how to accomplish my goal in Grunt (not in JS) using the above or any other tools? I don't mind adding a new tool, but I've come up short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xavier Priour set me on the right path, but I had to scratch my head a bit before I arrived at the final solution:

```
autonav: {
  options: {
    parent: '.nav'
  },
  dev: {
    files: [
     {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= dirs.purgatory %>/html',
        src: '**/*.html',
        dest: '<%= dirs.dev %>'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

First, I had to look into `expand`, which provided samples that used the `files` property Xavier mentioned. However, the examples show that `files` is an array of objects. Not sure if it "has" to be, but I followed that pattern and wrapped it up as an array.

Next was realizing it wasn't the input string that was wrong, it was that I was configuring the copy incorrectly. When expanded, the destination is a recreation of the source path. To get around this, you issue a CWD. This means that your input path is essentially "null"-ish and it doesn't create a "purgatory" directory in the destination.

The final task now works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

To use dynamic file lists in grunt and all its plugins, you need to wrap your src/dest in a files object and set `expand` to true:

```
autonav: {
  options: {
    parent: '.nav'
  },
  dev: {
    files: {
      expand: true,
      src: '<%= dirs.purgatory %>/html/**/*.html',
      dest: '<%= dirs.dev %>'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't come across this pattern before, but I tried it, which returned an error still. But I thought you were onto something with "expand", so I unwrapped it from the "files" object and kept the `expand: true`. It processed the files this time! However... not correctly. If the original developer is using the wildcard as the input string, it's not going to find the nav item and update it properly. :) That's not your problem, though-- your "expand: true" line has got me one step closer! Maybe I need to review the author's source code. Thanks!